# Getting "pre-check failed" error with missing attributes in module configuration of NvM in AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar, automotive

I am encountering an error during the build process of my AUTOSAR project. The error message indicates that the pre-check results for the module configuration [/EcuCfg/NvM] have failed. The specific errors I am encountering are:

ERROR - missing attribute 'implementationConfigVariant' (type: EcucConfigurationVariantEnum, kind: attr)
ERROR - missing attribute 'moduleDescription' (type: BswImplementation, kind: ref)

I have checked my configuration and implementation files, but I can't seem to find any issues with the attributes mentioned in the error message. I have also ensured that the necessary references are properly defined.

Has anyone experienced similar errors during the build process in the context of an AUTOSAR project? What could be the possible reasons for these errors, and how can I resolve them?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!